Issues with Colleagues Triggering Power Automate Refresh Flow in Power BI Service
I have a Power BI Pro and Power Automate Premium subscription.
In my dashboard, I have two Power Automate triggers that either refresh the dashboard or create an Excel file and email it to the user who triggered the button.
When my colleagues open the dashboard and, for example, refresh the dashboard, the button shows "failed." I added the user in Power Automate under "Manage run-only permissions."
Who can help me?
